# visual studio C# listview save and load problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, checkbox

i have a problem with visual studio c# listview items that i cant found a solution over googling.

I've made from application with a listview, i can add, remove, update listview items.
I'm saving and loading the listview to/from file correctly with this code:

```
 private void saveListViewItems(string path, ListView lv)
    {
        var delimeteredListviewData = new List<string>();
        string delimeteredItems = string.Empty;

        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items)
        {

            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi in lvi.SubItems)
            {

                    delimeteredItems += lvsi.Text + "#";

            }
            delimeteredListviewData.Add(delimeteredItems);
        }


        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, delimeteredListviewData.ToArray());
    }

    private void loadListViewItems(string path, ListView lv)
    {

        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(line.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));

        }
    }
```

the problems is i have activated checkbox next to each item. i cant save listview items with checkbox checked. i want to save listview and load with selected items. thanks

[image]

Comment: You may save items to a file in the format for each line having `checkedstate,from,to,comment` and load by parsing it. So you may implement methods `SaveListBox(ListView sender, string filename)`, and `LoadListBox(ListView sender, string filename)` where you can use `Split(',')`.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i need a full solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
        List<string> delimeteredItems = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.CheckedItems)
        {
            string     item= String.Join("#", lvi.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Select(si=>si.Text));
            delimeteredItems.Add(item);
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\lines.txt", delimeteredItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only saving the string you need to save more information.
You can added add a IsChecked value together with your string.
You need a small wrapper class that holds both values as a property.

Then you can use serilization, it is a term to describe a way to convert an object to something you can store on disk.

There are many formats to pick from, but Json is a good readable format. You can download the Nuget package NewtonSoft.Json via the nuget package manager.

```
public class StoreListView
{
    public void StoreToDisk(string path, List<ItemDataHolder> list)
    {

        string theListInJsonFormat = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

        File.WriteAllText(path, theListInJsonFormat);
    }
}

public class ItemDataHolder
{
    public string SomeValuesYouWantToSave { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Managed the program to work.
I was wrong about the way reading/writing the text file.
now I'm using ini-parser nuget.

installed ini parser to project.
then:

using IniParser;

using IniParser.Model;

```
 private void saveListViewItems(string path, ListView lv)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string IPFrom;
        string IPFromval;
        string IPTO;
        string IPTOval;
        string Comment;
        string Commentval;
        string CheckState;
        string CheckStateval;
        int IPSectioncount;

        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = parser.ReadFile(path);



                while ( i < lv.Items.Count) {

                    if ((lv.Items[i].Selected) || (lv.Items[i].Checked))
                    {
                        CheckStateval = "1";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CheckStateval = "0";
                    }

                CheckState = "";
                CheckState = "CheckState";
                CheckState += String.Join(CheckState, i);
                IPFromval = lv.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;

                IPFromval = "";
                IPFrom = "IPFrom";
                IPFrom += String.Join(IPFrom, i);
                IPFromval = lv.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;

                IPTOval = "";
                IPTO = "IPTO";
                IPTO += String.Join(IPTO, i);
                IPTOval = lv.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;

                Commentval = "";
                Comment = "Comment";
                Comment += String.Join(Comment, i);
                Commentval = lv.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;




                data["IP"][CheckState] = CheckStateval;
                data["IP"][IPFrom] = IPFromval;
                data["IP"][IPTO] = IPTOval;
                data["IP"][Comment] = Commentval;



                i++;
                }


                IPSectioncount = lv.Items.Count;
                data["IP"]["IPSectionCount"] = IPSectioncount.ToString();
                parser.WriteFile(path, data);


    }


    private void loadListViewItems(string path, ListView lv)
    {
        string IPFrom;
        string IPTO;
        string Comment;
        string CheckState;
        string IPSectioncount;
        string row="";



        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = parser.ReadFile(path);

        IPSectioncount = data["IP"]["IPSectionCount"];
        int m = Int32.Parse(IPSectioncount);



        int i = 0;


        while ( i < m )
        {
            IPFrom = "";
            IPTO = "";
            Comment = "";
            row = "";


            IPFrom = "IPFrom";
            IPFrom += String.Join(IPFrom, i);
            IPFrom = data["IP"][IPFrom];


            IPTO = "IPTO";
            IPTO += String.Join(IPTO, i);
            IPTO = data["IP"][IPTO];


            Comment = "Comment";
            Comment += String.Join(Comment, i);
            Comment = data["IP"][Comment];

            CheckState = "CheckState";
            CheckState += String.Join(CheckState, i);
            CheckState = data["IP"][CheckState];

            row = String.Join(",",IPFrom,IPTO,Comment);


                            lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(row.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));

                            if (CheckState == "1")
                            {
                                lv.Items[i].Checked = true;
                            }



                i++;




        }





    }
```